# parse querystring to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have such string from cookie:

```
"io=ZCgMK9hyc95vNRBMAAAA; vsid=910vr1505908332008888; csrftoken=FQCHNYIOvrAQztBHPNQlCiy4xorlZVs5; sessionid=uaggm1q1rcxy2o49noaw4b6djg8j18by"
```

,and I need to parse it to javascript Object. I tried to use this RegExp:

```
var uri = socket.request.headers.cookie
        var queryString = {};
        uri.replace(
            new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
            function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; }
        );
```

but it doesn't work for me, because in cookie I have only params in string without any domain name. Of course I can just add some domain name in the beginning but I don't want to create such a ugly code

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate and fill in the object

```
var queryString = {};

uri.split(';').forEach(function(item) {
    var parts = item.split('=');
    queryString[parts[0].trim()] = parts[1].trim();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3VabP/)

It would seem easier to store the data as JSON in the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

this function works fine:

```
function parseCookies (request) {
    var list = {},
        rc = request.headers.cookie;

    rc && rc.split(';').forEach(function( cookie ) {
        var parts = cookie.split('=');
        list[parts.shift().trim()] = unescape(parts.join('='));
    });

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard [querystring.parse](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html%23querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options) with ';' as separator.